# Loading a string into simplexmlelement

Tags: php

I am trying to post some data to a web service. Evidently something is wrong on my side so they sent me some example code. The example allowed me to enter the data by hand and submit it into their service. It works and sends a text area full of XML data plus a user/id. I already have a page setup to poll my database and extract the outstanding orders. I am trying to send the txnid from paypal to the new page so it can compile the xml and send it. I figured I could drop the same code I used for my failed method. The xml is formatted correctly but something it wrong when I try to use the SimpleXMLElement function. This previously took the data passed from the text field and worked fine. Now I get this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'

Here is the code thats giving the error

```
include('connect-db.php');                                  

// get the records from the database
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM paypal_payment_info WHERE txnid = '" .$_GET['txnid']. "'"))
{
    // display records if there are records to display
   if ($result->num_rows > 0)
    {
        $row = $result->fetch_object();

        // set up a row for each record

        $webOrderXML = "<WorkOrder>
                  <OrderID>127834</OrderID>
                  <OrderType>test</OrderType>
                  <ProjectCode> </ProjectCode>
                  <ProjectShipDate></ProjectShipDate>
                  <RetailerPO></RetailerPO>
                  <LineItems>
                    <LineItem>
                      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
                      <ProductCode>3PF-DD-SLPGZ6</ProductCode>
                      <ProductUPC></ProductUPC>
                      <ItemDescription>Filename</ItemDescription>
                      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
                      <ItemSSCC></ItemSSCC>
                      <FileList>
                <Source>/images/" . $row->itemname. str_replace(' ', "", str_replace('"', "", $row->os0)).  str_replace('"', "", $row->os1) . str_replace('"', "", $row->os2). ".jpg </Source>
                      </FileList>
                    </LineItem>
                  </LineItems>
                  <CustomerBillingInfo>
                  </CustomerBillingInfo>
                  <CustomerShippingInfo>
                    <Name>".$row->firstname. " " . $row->lastname."</Name>
                    <Address1>".$row->street."</Address1>
                    <Address2> </Address2>
                    <City>".$row->city."</City>
                    <State>".$row->state. "</State>
                    <PostalCode>".$row->zipcode."</PostalCode>
                    <Country>".$row->country."</Country>
                    <ShippingMethod>UPS</ShippingMethod>
                    <ShipAccountNum></ShipAccountNum>
                    <ShipType>MTH</ShipType>
                    <DC> </DC>
                  </CustomerShippingInfo>
                  <OrderProperties>
                  </OrderProperties>
                </WorkOrder>";                                      


    }
    // if there are no records in the database, display an alert message
    else
    {
            echo "No results to display!";
    }

}
// show an error if there is an issue with the database query
else
{
        echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error;
}

// close database connection
$mysqli->close();


//$WebOrderXML = $_POST['webOrderXML'];//orderxml


$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($WebOrderXML); 

$orderidx = $sxml->OrderID;
```

The text is the same. I can copy and paste the resulting string into the other form and post it. That works fine but somewhere I'm missing something because the function does not like that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

attention if you haven't any record `$WebOrderXML` value is `null` for that this exception shown

**Fatal error**:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'

because `SimpleXMLElement()` `NULL` give in.
you can check  `$WebOrderXML` value with `empty()` that `$WebOrderXML` is not `NULL`  and you can put `SimpleXMLElement()` inside of `try` `catch` for control exception

```
if(!empty($WebOrderXML)){
  try{
      $sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($WebOrderXML);
  }catch(Exception $e){
      //show error or do some work
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even need to do this step. I bypassed it and sent the string to the soap client and it works fine.